# Is there a free version available in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, 2016, licensing

Until SharePoint 2013, there was a SharePoint foundation version, which is free.

In the latest release (2016) it is [deprecated](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346112%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Now in SharePoint 2016 or [Office 365](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_365) is there something like SharePoint foundation which is available for free? I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't keep using SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Comment: no, one of my clients wanted to migrate to 2016 or O365 if there is a free version like SharePoint foundation in them

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no a frank alternative for SharePoint Foundation at SharePoint 2016.

But you can still use [SharePoint 2016 as a trial](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51493) for 180 days using the following trial keys based on your selected edition:

- **Enterprise trial product key:** `NQGJR-63HC8-XCRQH-MYVCH-3J3QR`
- **Standard trial product key:** `RTNGH-MQRV6-M3BWQ-DB748-VH7DM`

After the trial version has expired, You should be aware of

- You will not be able to extend it.
- You should provide a SharePoint product key via Central Administration. However, you still can add lists, items in lists, but you can't create pages, sites.....etc.for more details check [EXTEND SHAREPOINT TRIAL PERIOD](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/02/25/extend-sharepoint-trial-period/)
- You can build a new environment with a new installation that I think it may be suitable for a development environment, but it will require additional work to prepare it and restore your farm/custom solution every 6 months.

I also listed all possible alternatives at [SHAREPOINT FOUNDATION 2016 WHAT’S THE ALTERNATIVE?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/23/sharepoint-foundation-2016-whats-the-alternative/)

Answer (score 12):

As per following article

> Previous releases of SharePoint Server included SharePoint Foundation,
>   a free edition of SharePoint that included most of the core
>   functionality and architecture provided by the commercial editions of
>   SharePoint. SharePoint Foundation is no longer available in the
>   SharePoint Server 2016 release.

[What's deprecated or removed from SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346112(v=office.16).aspx)

Comment: The article above spells out that there is no such free offering for SharePoint 2016 available. You can start a trial with Office 365 but, apart from charities and non-profit organisation, there is not free subscriptions available.

Comment: There are no more free versions, how many times does he have to say it?

Comment: When it comes to Microsoft - no, there isn't. As to competitors, if that's what you meant - I have absolutely no idea as they are, at this point in time, outwith my current knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

There is a trial version of Office 365 that is available for free. 
You have 30 days of full functionality + 30 days grace period. The subscription is available [here](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-enterprise-e3-business-software) and allows you to create 25 users + unlimited ([almost](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)) number of site collections.

It is great for development and testing, but unsuitable for production unless you are planning to "jump" and move data from subscription to subscription every few months.

Comment: I found it is also relatively "inexpensive" to have one subscription for development and learning. It won't work as one off - the trial will do that just fine - but if you keep working on Office 365, it could come in handy.

Comment: Good suggestion. Found here a one year free dev subscription: http://dev.office.com/devprogram

Comment: I stand corrected, excellent find @grisha! Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

There are no more free versions. Yes, that is reality. Now what are the options?

1. You can use the [trial version of SharePoint 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51493), which is valid for 180 days.
2. The second option, if you or your company own an [MSDN subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa336858.aspx), is that you use SharePoint 2016 for free for development purposes. You can't use it for production.
3. With MSDN subscription, you will also get the one year Office 365 subscription. again for development purposes only.
4. Get the free [Office 365 development subscription](https://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/wizardnp.aspx?wizid=14b845d0-938c-45af-b061-f798fbb4d170&lcid=1033)

Answer (score 1):

There is a one years trial version of Office 365 that is available for free. 
You have 365 days of full functionality + 30 days grace period. The subscription is available [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program) and allows you to create 25 users + unlimited (almost) number of site collections. 
Prerequisites is Need.

1. Outlook account.
2. LinkedIn Profile
   After Successful registration for the  Office 365 Developer Program , we will get the email with the redeem  link.
   You got free 365 E3 plan with 25 users and Multiple site creation as well as all E3 bundle tools like. 
   Team, 
   Flow, 
   PowerApps,
   PowerBi limited version.
   Word.
   Excel.
   Yammer.
   Etc.

If you got the free version so press the positive button in my favour and enjoy.
For more details [Please go through this link](https://sharepointdiv.wordpress.com/2019/01/24/free-subscription-sharepoint-online-for-one-year/)

Answer (score 0):

You can with SharePoint 2019.
Download 2010 sharepoint and then go into the files and configure config.json and edit the code :

```
}
UAGE
[type=cloud-prov]
}{
```

To

```
}
UAGE
[type=cloud-<your exact windows version e.g. 1.23.8.46.6>][payment=successful]
[trial=false][uptime=cron-none]
}
```