# Get Sharepoint 2013 for private use

Tags: sharepoint-server, development-enviroment

I was working until recently at a big company. I worked mainly with SharePoint 2013 and started to really like the environment. Now that I changed the city for my studies, I finished the job. Is there any way to get SharePoint 2013 running on a normal laptop? Is there any option to host the system online without the need to have Windows server installed on my PC? Or what would you recommend? I now about SharePoint 2016 but as I want to learn how to develop web parts for SharePoint 2013, I don't think it would be the best option for me.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I see it, you have 3 options:

**- Request a [30-day Office 365 trial](https://products.office.com/en/try)**

With Office 365, you can have access to the latest SharePoint version without needing your own infrastructure. You can also email O365Dev at microsoft.com and ask for a developer subscription and they may give you a **one-year** Enterprise edition of Office 365.

**- Setup and/or download an existing SharePoint 2010/2013/2016 Virtual Machine**

2013 is the last version to have a free edition, [SharePoint Foundation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42039). You can grab this, or [find a Server VM online](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint%202013%20virtual%20machine%20download). There used to be a couple but now most of them are broken links. There is also a [2016 trial available](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193500/is-there-a-free-version-available-in-sharepoint-2016).

You can also look for free software (e.g. Windows Server) through [MSDN/DreamSpark](https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/Catalog) programs, specially if you are a student.

**- Try installing SP in Windows**

There are a couple of [hacks](http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1) to allow you to install and develop on a non-server windows operating system, but it could be a bit complicated and involves editing the registry, etc., so I would think of this only on a worse case scenario.

More:

[Are there any SharePoint virtual machines available from Microsoft?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/are-there-any-sharepoint-virtual-machines-available-from-microsoft)

[Installing Sharepoint 2013 Windows 7](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41204/installing-sharepoint-2013-windows-7)

[Is there a free version available in SharePoint 2016?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193500/is-there-a-free-version-available-in-sharepoint-2016)