# Are there limitations for SharePoint Server 2016 Trial?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Does the trial version of SharePoint Server 2016 have any limitation just for being trial?

How long can I use it before it explodes?

I want to be able to explore some advanced functionalities such as:

- Hybrid architecture
- Power BI
- Creating some SP add-ins
- Migrate large volumes of files

I need time to create some POCs and present to some people. Can I backup a trial SP farm before it explodes and when I activate my licence will I be able to resume from where I stoped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint server 2016 has full-featured software for a 180-day trial using the following product key:

Enterprise trial product key: NQGJR-63HC8-XCRQH-MYVCH-3J3QR

Standard trial product key: RTNGH-MQRV6-M3BWQ-DB748-VH7DM

After the SharePoint Trial Period has expired. You will not be able to create pages, sites..etc.However, you can continue to use the expired trail version to add lists, items in lists.

In addition, we can’t use the SharePoint trial version in a production environment.

More information for your reference:

https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/extend-sharepoint-trial-period/

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sharepoint-server-2016

Answer (score 1):

You can check below answer, here is a very good explanation about the SharePoint 2016 trial version :

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/193520/87201

Notes :

There are 2 separate trial keys:

SharePoint Server 2016 : NQGJR-63HC8-XCRQH-MYVCH-3J3QR

Project Server 2016 : Y2WC2-K7NFX-KWCVC-T4Q8P-4RG9W

Both will valid for 180 days.

More details here :

[Office Servers Evaluations](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/evalcenter/evaluate-sharepoint-server-2016)

[Great news - SharePoint Server 2016 Trial is available!](https://blog.libinuko.com/2016/03/08/great-news-sharepoint-server-2016-trial-is-available/)